# Redemption to Process Incoming Email in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto, mapi

I am working to process the incoming email received from exchange server. Previously I used NewMailEx to fire for incoming mails. But this works only when Outlook is online. I need to make it to work even when Outlook is offline.

So I am now moving on to the powerful tool called Redemption. But I can't get started  here.

My previous code is for your reference.

```
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
    _Explorers = this.Application.Explorers;
    _Inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;

    _Explorers.Application.NewMailEx += new
    Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_NewMailEx);
    outlookNamespace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  }

  private void Application_NewMailEx(string EntryID)
  {
    Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem)_Explorers.Application.Session.GetItemFromID(
    EntryID, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
  }
```

How can I get the body of an incoming email through redemption? Or is there any other way to fire incoming messages even when outlook is offline.

I am using Outlook 2007 and Microsoft Exchange Server and developing using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder.
`RDOSession.NewMailEx` won't fire either when you are offline - this is just how MAPI works. `NewMail` event fires when a message arrives. When a new item is synchronized from the server, only `Items.ItemAdd` event will fire on the parent folder.

Comment: So in my code, if I replace NewMailEx with NewMail, will my problem be solved?